# Framework with simple ACL out of the box

Tags: php, acl

I'm a (hobby) PHP guy. I have experienced Fuelphp and loved it simple ACL solution out of the box. The big downside of Fuelphp is its small community.

I have seen many articles about Laravel, but I read the manual and found that it only have Authentication, not Authorization. Must install plugin which develop by 3rd party.

Symfony has ACL but it's seem complicated.

I even tried frameworks in other language like Playframework, Grails but like Laravel, it doesn't have ACL feature. In case of Grails, Spring Security plugin seem to be very complicated.

Could you please suggest some frameworks (php is preferred) that has simple ACL support right out of the box?

Thank you

Comment: If symfony is to big for you, take a look at [silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/). It is build on symfony components so it resembles in some ways. You can find an ACL demo built with silex [here](https://github.com/davedevelopment/silex-acl-demo)

Comment: You can check this for Laravel : https://medium.com/laravel-4/laravel-4-acl-a7f2fa1f9791

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at [phalcon](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/acl.html) framework. As it's documentation says:

> Phalcon\Acl provides an easy and lightweight management of ACLs as well as the permissions attached to them.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I want. In addition, I found Grails plugin named Shiro that's pretty easy to use. I know it's not PHP and it's just plugin, not in the core, but I still find it's easy.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel have a package now. Check this link.
[Laravel authentication-acl](https://github.com/intrip/laravel-authentication-acl) on Github.

**Some of the Features**

- User authentication and signup
- Configurable email confirmation
- Configurable captcha integration
- Can create groups and permissions and associate permissions to user
  or group
- Any user can have multiple groups and permissions

Edit: Visit [this page](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/acl-in-laravel) for other ACL packages (extension) for Laravel.